# Is there a way to change the characters assigned to keyboard keys?

Tags: mac, keyboard, macbook, keyboard-layout

So I spilled coffee on my macbook keyboard and now the "r" key, and only the "r" key, doesn't work. As a workaround, I'm hoping to assign the r character to one of the number keys. Is this possible?

Comment: are the keycaps removable?  you may be able to pop the `R` key off and swab with isopropyl alcohol to clean it.

Comment: Yes, tried that. Had some odd results right after (the computer started acting like I was always pressing the "r") but a day later it's back to normal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tried that by myself, but this software seems to be what you need :

http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele

Comment: Thanks. This does look like what I need. Unfortunately saving the new keyboard layout to the Library requires an administrator password, and my password has an r in it… But thanks

Comment: you don't have a visual keyboard to do so ?

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. But after two days, the keyboard came back. So I'm good. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I use that application to write the `\` with `Cmd + 0.` I don't know if you can use only one key as a hot key there.
https://www.shadowlab.org/softwares/spark.php